# NAT TCP/UDP Connections With iptables on AWS

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, amazon-web-services, nat

So I've got 2 instances on AWS set up so I can SSH into them directly (A, B) from my home machine C.

But I want to set up box A so that I can forward certain UDP and TCP connections from it to box B.

IPtables seems to be what I want for this (rinetd would be nice, but it seems that project is dead and it only covers TCP).

I followed various tutorials, but they don't seem to work + I would think I'd need another rule anyway.

These are the rules as I've configured them on box A for forwarding an SSH session through box A to B:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1044 -j DNAT --to-destination B:22 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source A
```

I read this as 'take TCP packets received on port 1044, change their destination from box A to box B'
And then 'as I send the modified packets back onto the network, change their source to myself (A)'

The tutorial(s) seem to think only these two commands are needed, but they don't work.

I'm wondering how box A is supposed to take responses from B and modify their source to itself + forward them back to C...

Comment: `--to-destination C:22` seems wrong.  C is the client machine, the destination is B, right?  Should be B:22, shouldn't it?

Comment: You're right, though that was a typo when I made this post -- not in the command.  Thanks.  Also, I'll add I looked at another option called socat, but I believe that involves bringing packets into user space.

Comment: You need to tell us about the network setup (how these two machines are connected). Usually, we do such setup when A is the default gateway of B. However, it will not work (as is) when both machines are on the same subnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you may need to enable ip forwarding.

sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

to get your machine to be a router.  Full details on ip forwarding are [here](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/).

Second, I won't swear to this but your iptables rules look wrong to me.  It seems you need something more like this:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 1044 -j DNAT --to-destination B:22
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d B --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

You may not need the second line if your default policy is to accept, then it may only be that you don't have ip forwarding enabled.  However, what you are doing is a bit odd, the packets are going in and out on the same interface. I never tried that.

Your second POSTROUTING line, this seems wrong or misleading.  If you need this line at all, you probably want to narrow the filter down to port 22 to B.

Also, tcpdump is your friend!  Use tcpdump to look to see if these packets in and out are really getting modified.

Comment: The ip forwarding was it, wonder why it's off by default...